# How do I get chained shortcuts to work on HomePod?

Tags: shortcuts-app, homepod

I have iOS Shortcuts that call other shortcuts. Shortcut A creates an input for Shortcut X and calls Shortcut X. Shortcut B creates a different input for Shortcut X and calls Shortcut X. Shortcut X starts with "Receive `Text` input from `Nothing`. If there's no input: `Continue`"

On my iPhone, I can run Shortcuts A and B via "Hey, Siri" with no further prompting, but when I run them via Siri on my HomePod, they fail while waiting for me to respond to an input prompt on the iPhone.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or is this just a bug in homeOS?

Answer (score 0):

Short term, you will have to remove the chance a dialog could be presented to get the workflow to run on a device that can’t pop up the dialog to choose a selection.

Maybe Apple decides they will try to run the next script to see if it needs a dialog in some update, but for now my impression/experience is the chance it will need the phone UI for something unexpected to me will stop your automation when executing in HomePod.

Comment: (a) How do I remove the chance a dialog could be presented...? I thought I did that with "Receive `Text` input from `Nothing`. If there's no input: `Continue`". (b) I don't have a dialog presented when I run the shortcut on the iPhone, so why is it being presented on the iPhone when being run from HomePod?

Comment: I agree with you @OldPro - I’m scratching my head on this one since Siri invocation should work the same anywhere - it’s quite a hassle for me to learn this topic without a script editor or debugger, but I’m sure others smarter and more experienced with shortcuts than I may have some excellent ideas for you. I hope to learn from you and your question here, too.